# Git Init --Bare Error - fatal: Out of memory? mmap failed: No such device

Tags: git

I get that on initializing a bare repository, though there is about 1GB ram available in my remote machine. I've also taken a look at [git add error : "fatal : malloc, out of memory"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/675247/git-add-error-fatal-malloc-out-of-memory), but it does not really help.

I don't understand why this error is created, it seems quite weird. Why does this happen ?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Do you have a directory/file named "config" in your "bare" repo?

See http://www.bitchx.com/log/git-f/git-f-20-Mar-2010/git-f-20-Mar-2010-03.php ([mirror](http://web.archive.org/web/20120321104146/http://www.bitchx.com/log/git-f/git-f-20-Mar-2010/git-f-20-Mar-2010-03.php))

EDIT: if so, you should **almost certainly** not be using `git init --bare` - bare is meant for **empty** "server" repositories that you intent to push to, not for initializing a new repo from a working tree.

Comment: i'm creating a repository from a project folder. This is a totally new repository, the first one.

Comment: See my edit: if you're creating a new repo from a working directory, you should not be using the --bare option.

Comment: *sigh* git confuses me more and more. I want a remote repository that will not be a working copy. Sort of like a subversion remote repository. People told me that this has to be a bare repos. Then i can clone a working copy on my local machine. Should i first create a standard non bare repos in my remote pc and then initialize a bare one(again in the remote) to clone to my local machine ?

Comment: To clone to your remote, I'd `git clone --mirror ./myrepo ./bareclone` and then rsync the `bareclone` over to the server

Comment: The remote repo should normally be a bare one; you can also push to non-bare repos, but that's a lot more hassle. If you've already got a tree of code, you can create a (NON-BARE) repo on the base directory of that tree, and commit the code into that repo. Seperately, you need to create a BARE repo on your remote machine (up to this point, the order doesn't matter) and then link your local to the remote using something like "git remote add origin user@remote.machine:/path/to/repo" and "push origin master" from your local repo.

Comment: so, i created an empty bare repos successfully now. Would it be a good idea to check it out(clone) on my local machine and "git add" the files from there ? And then push to the remote ?

Comment: that would work. personally, I prefer to initialize a non-bare repo in my local tree and then add the remote, as I mentioned up in the comments.

Comment: Thanks for this answer. Ran into this problem, config was already a directory.

Answer (score 9):

First, that's a very bizarre error message.

Second, what you need to do is this:

1. In your source directory:

   git init
2. Then, somewhere else:

   git clone --bare `<your source directory`> `<name you want for your repository`>.git

e.g.,

```
git clone --bare my-source my-source.git
```

You can then copy the resultant bare repository to your remote location and clone it.

For completeness, a different way to do this is:

1. Create an empty bare repository:

   mkdir my-source.git

   cd my-source.git

   git init --bare
2. Go to your source directory and make it a git repo (non-bare):

   cd /path/to/my-source

   git init
3. Add the bare repo as remote origin:

   git remote add origin /path/to/my-source.git
4. And push the contents of your repo to the remote:

   git push --all

If running `git init` (without `--bare`) inside your source directory gives this error, you have a different problem.