# Git init --bare giving error fatal: Out of memory? mmap failed: No such device

Tags: git, ubuntu, homestead

I have checked the available memory and looks like there is plenty of it:

```
vagrant@homestead:~$ free -m
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:          2001        869       1131         21         22        252
-/+ buffers/cache:        594       1406
Swap:          767          0        767
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Check http://stackoverflow.com/a/5670853/1860929

Comment: I saw this post but it doesn't solve the problem it's merely a workaround.

Answer (score 1):

I found the issue.  It was being caused by git trying to create a config file in the directory that a /config directory already existed.

I have now removed the /config directory and was able to run `git init --bare`

However, this is a problem with all of my apps as they all contain /config directories.  Does anyone know a workaround?

Comment: If you are trying to create a repository in the same place as the files in the repository, I do not think you want the `--bare` option